# Meteor js Classes and contet

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, meteor

Im trying to use meteor classes in my project. In my class im using an npm module `nodemailer` which provides a custom handler for setting the socket like this:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({....});

transpot.getSocket = function (options, callback) {  // <-- here
   console.log('get socket');
}
```

So i tried to wrap it up in the meteor code with class:

```
var nodemailer = Meteor.npmRequire('nodemailer');

class TestNodemailerMeteor {

    constructor(options) {
           //....  
         this.name = options.name;
    }
    initMailer(){
        this.transport = nodemailer.createTransport({//set options});

        this.transport.getSocket = this.getSocket;


    }
    getSocket(options, callback){
          // 
         console.log(this.name); // this.name is undefined, lost this context here
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the `transport.getSocket` is getting called from the module, im loosing the class context with all the variables and methods. Is there a way to attach the module function to the class object method, without loosing class context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable with [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Try this:

```
    this.transport.getSocket = this.getSocket.bind(this);
```

This may or may not be the right way of using bind here, but hopefully this will lead you into the right direction.

Comment: thanks this help me. now i started to understand how to solve context problems